# WHERE clause is slower with value from CTE than with constant?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I want to have a variable cached during a query performing on **Postgres 12**. I followed the approach of having CTE like below:

```sql
-- BEGIN PART 1
with cached_vars as (
    select max(datetime) as datetime_threshold
    from locations
    where distance > 70
      and user_id = 9087
)
-- END PART 1
-- BEGIN PART 2
select *
from locations
where user_id = 9087
  and datetime > (select datetime_threshold from cached_vars)
-- END PART 2
```

Running the above query will lead to performance issues. I expected the total runtime to approximately equal `(part1 runtime + part2 runtime)`, but it takes a lot longer.

Notably, there is no performance issue when I run only the 2nd part with manual `datetime_threshold`.

`locations` table is defined as:

```
 id | user_id | datetime | location | distance | ...
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to reduce the total runtime to something like `(part1 runtime + part2 runtime)`?

Comment: . . I don't understand your question.  Your two "performance estimates" are the same equation.

Comment: @partizaans have you considered using a temporary table to hold date from first query? You can give it a try. Please look into my answer.

Comment: To get the best solution, please explain the objective of the query. Is `distance > 70` a constant filter? What else is variable? Do you need `SELECT *` or is a small subset of columns enough? Please share basic information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation behind the difference you observed is this:

Postgres has column statistics and can adapt the query plan depending on the value of a provided **constant** for `datetime_threshold`. With favorable filter values, this can lead to a much more efficient query plan.

In the other case, when `datetime_threshold` has to be computed in another `SELECT` first, Postgres has to default to a generic plan. `datetime_threshold` could be anything.

The difference will become obvious in `EXPLAIN` output.

To make sure Postgres optimizes the second part for the actual `datetime_threshold` value, you can either run two separate queries (feed the result of query 1 as constant to query 2), or use dynamic SQL to force re-planning of query 2 every time in a PL/pgSQL function.

#### For example

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_user_id int, _distance int = 70)
  RETURNS SETOF locations
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
     'SELECT *
      FROM   locations
      WHERE  user_id = $1
      AND    datetime > $2'
   USING _user_id
      , (SELECT max(datetime)
         FROM   locations
         WHERE  distance > _distance
         AND    user_id = _user_id);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo(9087);
```

Related:

- [Dynamic ORDER BY and ASC / DESC in a plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775242/dynamic-order-by-and-asc-desc-in-a-plpgsql-function/49775746#49775746)
- [Optional argument in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519410/optional-argument-in-pl-pgsql-function/11604187#11604187)

In extreme cases, you might even use another dynamic query to calculate `datetime_threshold`. But I don't expect that's necessary.

As for ["something useful in the docs"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> [...] The important difference is that `EXECUTE` will re-plan the
> command on each execution, generating a plan that is specific to the
> current parameter values; whereas PL/pgSQL may otherwise create a
> generic plan and cache it for re-use. **In situations where the best
> plan depends strongly on the parameter values, it can be helpful to
> use `EXECUTE` to positively ensure that a generic plan is not selected.**

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Indexes

Perfect indexes would be:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON locations (user_id, distance DESC NULL LAST, date_time DESC NULLS LAST); -- for query 1
CREATE INDEX ON locations (user_id, date_time);           -- for query 2
```

Fine tuning depends on undisclosed details. Partial index might be an option.

There may be any number of additional reasons why your query is slow. Not enough details.

Comment: Thanks. So is there any idiomatic way to have `datetime_threshold` as a constant to avoid such performance issues that are caused by the `select` statement in the `where` clause of the second part? Of course, I can handle this problem in the application layer over the DB level but I got curious about this while being unable to find anything useful on the docs.

Comment: I added an example solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to perform well, I would suggest adding the indexes `locations(user_id, distance)` and `locations(user_id, datetime)`.

I would also phrase the query using window functions:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             max(datetime) filter (where distance > 70) over (partition by userid) as datetime_threshold
      from location l
      where userid = 9087
     ) l
where datetime > datetime_threshold;
```

Window functions often improve performance.  However, with the right indexes, I don't know if the two versions will be substantially different.

Comment: That didn't help also. There is no problem with the indexes. The `with` clause runs in 2 secs approx. And the second part takes 1.5 secs if the dynamic part [I mean `(select datetime_threshold from cached_vars)` statement] is substituted with the result of the first part [sth like '2021-03-14 14:40:23.000000 +00:00']. The combination of these parts breaks the performance (the query takes more than 2 minutes to perform).

Answer (score 0):

Please break the query into two part and store the first part in a temp table (temporary table in PostgreSQL is only accessible in current database session.). Then join the temp table with second part. Hope it will speed up the processing time.

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_cached_vars (
       datetime_threshold timestamp
    );
    
    -- BEGIN PART 1
    with cached_vars as (
        select max(datetime) as datetime_threshold
        from locations
        where distance > 70
          and user_id = 9087
    )insert into temp_table_name select datetime_threshold from cached_vars 
    -- END PART 1
    -- BEGIN PART 2
    select *
    from locations
    where user_id = 9087
      and datetime > (select datetime_threshold from temp_table_cached_vars Limit 1)

-- END PART 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested your answer and the problem still exists. I have no idea why there is this huge difference when `datetime > (select datetime_threshold from temp_table_cached_vars )` is changed to sth like `datetime > '2021-03-14 15:17:23.000000'` and how to overcome that.

Comment: how many rows are there in locations table?

Comment: 1,300,000,000 approximately.

Comment: Would you please try with  distance <= 70 in where clause of second query? And please let me know the data type of datetime column.

Comment: Sure I did! That didn't help also.

Comment: And the datatype of datetime field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229898/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-partizaans).

Answer (score 0):

Just add Limi1 in the subquery as I used in below example.

```
-- BEGIN PART 1
with cached_vars as (
    select max(datetime) as datetime_threshold
    from locations
    where distance > 70
      and user_id = 9087
)
-- END PART 1
-- BEGIN PART 2
select *
from locations
where user_id = 9087
  and datetime > (select datetime_threshold from cached_vars Limit 1)
-- END PART 2
```

Comment: Thanks again, I tried your answer the performance issue still exists. I think the problem is from the query itself as @erwin-brandstetter mentioned in his answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to

```
with cached_vars as not materialized (
```

Visit https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257014/are-there-side-effects-to-postgres-12s-not-materialized-directive for explanation