# How to use text input as column name(s) in a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-13

I'm working with Postgres and PostGIS. Trying to write a function that that selects specific columns according to the given argument.

I'm using a `WITH` statement to create the result table before converting it to `bytea` to return.
**The part I need help with is the `$4` part**. I tried it is demonstrated below and `$4::text` and both give me back the text value of the input and not the column value in the table if `cols=name` so I get back from the query name and not the actual names in the table. I also try `data($4)` and got type error.
The code is like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_by_txt(z integer,x integer,y integer, cols text)
        RETURNS bytea
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
declare
res bytea;
begin
    WITH bounds AS (
      SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom
    ),
    mvtgeom AS (
      SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom, $4
      FROM table1 t, bounds
      WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
    )
    
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.select_by_txt')
    INTO res
    FROM mvtgeom;
    RETURN res;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Example for calling the function:

```
select_by_txt(10,32,33,"col1,col2")
```

The argument cols can be multiple column names from 1 and not limited from above. The names of the columns inside `cols` will be checked before calling the function that they are valid columns.

Comment: `cols` sounds like you are trying to pass *multiple* column names. Is that so? How many can it be? Please show example calls.

Comment: yes, I've updated the post with an example as you ask @ErwinBrandstetter
the answer below of JGH works for me with just one column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing multiple column names as concatenated string for dynamic execution urgently requires decontamination. I suggest a [`VARIADIC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) function parameter instead, with properly quoted identifiers (using `quote_ident()` in this case):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_by_txt(z int, x int, y int, VARIADIC cols text[] = NULL, OUT res text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
$$
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.select_by_txt')
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom%s
   FROM   table1 t
   JOIN  (SELECT ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3)) AS bounds(geom)
          ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
   ) mvtgeom
$$, (SELECT ', ' || string_agg(quote_ident (col), ', ') FROM unnest(cols) col)
   )
   INTO  res
   USING z, x, y;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=74c2bc90c18cc2e931a117f0b1b78ba6)*

The format specifier `%I` for `format()` deals with a *single* identifier. You have to put in more work for *multiple* identifiers, especially for a variable number of 0-n identifiers. This implementation quotes every single column name, and only add a `,` if any column names have been passed. So it **works for every possible input**, even no input at all. Note `VARIADIC cols text[] = NULL` as last input parameter with NULL as default value:

- [Optional argument in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519410/optional-argument-in-pl-pgsql-function/11604187#11604187)

Related:

- [quote_ident() does not add quotes to column name "first"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662580/quote-ident-does-not-add-quotes-to-column-name-first/66664718#66664718)

Column names are case sensitive in this context!

Call for your example (important!):

```
SELECT select_by_txt(10,32,33,'col1', 'col2');
```

Alternative syntax:

```
SELECT select_by_txt(10,32,33, VARIADIC '{col1,col2}');
```

More revealing call, with a third column name and malicious (though futile) intent:

```
SELECT select_by_txt(10,32,33,'col1', 'col2', $$col3'); DROP TABLE table1;--$$);
```

About that odd third column name and SQL injection:

- https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables

About `VAIRADIC` parameters:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)
- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)

Using an `OUT` parameter for simplicity. That's totally optional. See:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)

#### What I would ***not*** do

If you really, really trust the input to be a properly formatted list of 1 or more valid column names at all times - and you asserted that ...

> the names of the columns inside cols will be checked before calling the function that they are valid columns

You *could* simplify:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_by_txt(z int, x int, y int, cols text, OUT res text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
$$
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.select_by_txt')
FROM  (
   SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom, %s
   FROM   table1 t
   JOIN  (SELECT ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3)) AS bounds(geom)
          ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
   ) mvtgeom
$$, cols
   )
   INTO  res
   USING z, x, y;
END
$func$;
```

(How can you be so sure that the input will always be reliable?)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a [dynamic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_by_txt(z integer,x integer,y integer, cols text)
        RETURNS bytea
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
declare
res bytea;
begin
EXECUTE format('
    WITH bounds AS (
      SELECT ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3) AS geom
    ),
    mvtgeom AS (
      SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom, %I
      FROM table1 t, bounds
      WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326))
    )
    
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, ''public.select_by_txt'')
    FROM mvtgeom', cols)
    INTO res
    USING z,x,y;
    
    RETURN res;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Hi, First, thank you for responding! The answer you gave me is partly working for me. It's working when cols is single-column input but when cols='col1,co2' the function fails with this error - ERROR: column \"{col1,col2}\" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703). there is a way to "tell" the function that cols is not a single column?

Comment: @Yoad This answers your question as it was originally written. If you have a new question feel free to ask a new question in a new post.

Comment: The original question was for columns so it's still the same question... I've added an example because I saw that maybe this is not so clear.
if this is important for you I can re-ask the question in a new post