# Access column using variable instead of explicit column name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I would like to access a column by using variable instead of a static column name.
Example:

```
variable := 'customer';

SELECT table.variable (this is what I would prefer) instead of table.customer
```

I need this functionality as records in my table vary in terms of data length (eg. some have data in 10 columns, some in 14 or 16 columns etc.) so I need to address columns dynamically. As I understand, I can't address columns by their index (eg. select 8-th column of the table) right?

I can loop and put the desired column name in a variable for the given iteration. However, I get errors when I try to access a column using that variable (e.g. `table_name.variable` is not working).

For the sake of simplicity, I paste just some dummy code to illustrate the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_column_name() returns text
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
col_name text;
return_value text;

BEGIN

create table customer (
    id bigint,
    name varchar
);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES(1, 'Adam');

col_name := 'name';

-- SELECT customer.name INTO return_value FROM customer WHERE id = 1; -- WORKING, returns 'Adam' but it is not DYNAMIC.
-- SELECT customer.col_name INTO return_value FROM customer WHERE id = 1; -- ERROR:  column customer.col_name does not exist
-- SELECT 'customer.'||col_name INTO return_value FROM customer WHERE id = 1; -- NOT working, returns 'customer.name'
-- SELECT customer||'.'||col_name INTO return_value FROM customer WHERE id = 1; -- NOT working, returns whole record + .name, i.e.: (1,Adam).name

DROP TABLE customer;
RETURN return_value;
END;
$$;

SELECT dynamic_column_name();
```

So how to obtain 'Adam' string with SQL query using `col_name` variable when addressing column of `customer` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not allow to parameterize identifiers  (incl. column names) or syntax elements. Only *values* can be parameters.

You need dynamic SQL for that. (Basically, build the SQL string and execute.) Use [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a plpgsql function. There are multiple syntax variants. For your simple example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_column_name(_col_name text, OUT return_value text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM customer WHERE id = 1', _col_name)
   INTO return_value;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT dynamic_column_name('name');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e7b45ac4e8dfdba8eabf99d55007473)*

Data types have to be compatible, of course.

More examples:

- [How to use text input as column name(s) in a Postgres function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350225/how-to-use-text-input-as-column-names-in-a-postgres-function/67370823#67370823)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D+%5Bdynamic-sql%5D+parameter+column+code%3AEXECUTE

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin Brandstetter! Execute and format allowed me to solve my real case problem.

I wonder if I can apply the same to the CURSOR? I.e. I would like to traverse each row(record) and do something with its values. However I still need to access the columns using a variable (e.g. cursor.variable   instead of   cursor.name).
I managed to do the task by traversing table using subsequent IDs and with each iteration selecting desired values by searching with that ID - which is inefficient. I was unable to achieve that with Cursor which sould save me the searching by ID every iteration

Comment: @jans: You might ask another *question* with all relevant details about that cursor thing.