# SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION display_columns_data(table_name varchar, columns_to_display varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE (result_row json) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    'SELECT ' || array_to_string(columns_to_display, ',') || ' FROM ' || table_name;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
SELECT * FROM display_columns_data('employees', ARRAY['first_name', 'last_name']);
```

```
Detail: Returned type character varying(20) does not match expected type json in column 1.  
Where: SQL statement "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees"
PL/pgSQL function display_columns_data(character varying,character varying\[\]) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: Well the query you are building returns two varchar columns, but your function is declared to return a single json column. What do you actually want?

Comment: Right.  SQL will not automatically do that conversion for you.  You have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query inside the method is returning a result set containing columns of type character varying(20), or strings, which is why you're getting the issue. The function display_columns_data is designed to return a table with a single column of type json. The issue is brought on by a discrepancy between the defined return type and the actual result set.

Try this code for your function definition;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION display_columns_data(table_name varchar, columns_to_display varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE (result_row record) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    'SELECT ' || array_to_string(columns_to_display, ',') || ' FROM ' || table_name;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The RETURNS TABLE clause in the above code specifies that the function should produce a table with a single column named result_row having type record .This will match the result set produced by the dynamic SQL query, which may have columns of different types depending on the input columns_to_display.

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to return a JSON object you have to cast the columns to JSON within your `SELECT` statement;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION display_columns_data(table_name varchar, columns_to_display varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE (result_row json) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    'SELECT json_build_object(' || array_to_string(columns_to_display, ',') || ') FROM ' || table_name;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns a set of JSON values, each wrapping a row with the given column names, while preserving said column names as key names. And **safely**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION display_columns_data(table_name text, columns_to_display text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (result json)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format (
      'SELECT to_json((SELECT t FROM (SELECT %s) t)) FROM %I'
    , (SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(col), ', ') FROM unnest(columns_to_display) col)  -- !
    , table_name
   );
END
$func$;
```

Note how I unnest the array of column names and run them through `quote_ident()` individually to shut the door for SQL injection, which was wide open. Column names have to be passed unquoted and case-sensitive.

See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [How to use text input as column name(s) in a Postgres function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350225/how-to-use-text-input-as-column-names-in-a-postgres-function/67370823#67370823)